# Minimum degree for an irreducible polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

Is it true that for every non-closed field $\mathbb F$ exists a polynomial of degree 2 that is irreducible over $\mathbb F$?
This holds for $\mathbb Q, \mathbb R$ but I can't understand if it is always true.

Comment: No, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/93744/non-algebraically-closed-field-in-which-every-polynomial-of-degree-n-has-a-ro), or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2576354/if-every-polynomial-of-degree-2-is-reducible-then-k-is-algebraically-closed?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: What's *non-close* field?

Comment: @Bernard I mean a field which is not algebraically closed

Answer (score 0):

No. See for instance the field of [straightedge-and-compass (complex) constructible numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_number).

Another example is like this: consider $\overline {\Bbb F}_p$, inside which you have exaclty one copy of each $\Bbb F_{p^n}$. Then, $\bigcup_{m\in\Bbb N}\Bbb F_{p^{2^{m}}}$ is a subfield and it's as you mention.