# Are there irreducible polynomials of any degree over "most" fields?

Tags: field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Given a field $K$ that is neither algebraically closed nor real closed, must there necessarily be an irreducible polynomial of degree $n$ over $K$ for all positive integers $n$?

By the Artin-Schreier theorem, we know that irreducible polynomials of arbitrary large degrees must exist, but this does not necessarily mean that such polynomials exist for all degrees.

Comment: In the field of constructible algebraic numbers all polynomials of degree $2$ factor completely (and therefore the filed isn't real closed).

Comment: The comment above can be extended to find a field with no irreducible polynomials of degree $\le n$ for every n, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/93744/1039170).

Answer (score 4):

No. Let $K=\bigcup_n{\mathbb{F}_{p^{3^n}}}$. Then any polynomial in $K$ of degree $3^d >1$ is reducible, but the algebraic closure of $K$ is of infinite degree over $K$.

The same could be said by replacing the sequence $(3^n)_n$ with any increasing sequence $a_n$ such that $a_n|a_{n+1}$ and such that there exists a prime $q$ such that $v_q(a_n)$ is bounded: then there will be irreducible polynomials of degree a power of $q$ over $K$, but no irreducible polynomials of degree $r$ if $v_r(a_n)$ diverges.